# How can i zoom ionic page that contain HTML content?

Tags: html, typescript, ionic3, ionic4

I am trying load HTML string in ion-content but i am not able to zoom page like mobile safari.

```
url: string = "";    
    <ion-content padding>
      <div  [innerHTML]="url"></div>
    </ion-content>

url: string = "HTML String";
```

It loads html contant but i am not able to make pinch zoom on text

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `scrollX = "true"` to ion-content.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content